# How to add customer icons/markers on Google map fusion table

Tags: google-maps, google-fusion-tables

I have a fusion table layer on my map. But I want to use my own image as markers. I found the following link from Google maps api guide, but I have no clue how it works? I can't see any customer icons on the map?

https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/docs/samples/custom_markers?hl=en

Comment: Very useful question, would like to know it too.

Comment: I have stuck here by quite a while.... do not know what I can do.